# How to display ajax result in table row

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i have a function to insert the value to database . Everything is going well but i am stuck in ajax process to display the current value inserted in the new row of the table. I could not find a way to display or echo the values.I need an immediate help in this .can someone figure out what should i add to .
How can i echo value for ajax result to display in new row.

here is my modal..

```
    public function pinsert() {
    $amount = $this->input->post('amount');
    $paid_date = $this->input->post('paid_date');
    $project = $this->input->post('e1');

    $data = array(
        'paid_date' => $paid_date,
        'amount' => $amount,
        'pro_id' => $project
    );
    $this->db->insert('payment', $data);
   }
```

my controller

```
public function payment_insert() {
        $this->load->model('payment_model');
      $feed= $this->payment_model->pinsert();
      }
```

And lastly my jquery for ajax

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
                   $(".btn-primary").live('click',function(){
               var post_data=$('.modal-body').find('input,select').serialize();
              // var select=$('select').val();
                 $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: "<?php echo site_url("payment/payment_insert"); ?>",
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: post_data,
                        success: function(result)
                        {
                        // console.log(result);
                             var $tr = $('<tr/>');
$tr.append($('<td/>').html(result.p_id));
$tr.append($('<td/>').html(result.project_title));
$tr.append($('<td/>').html(result.amount));
$tr.append($('<td/>').html(result.paid_date));
$tr.append($('<td/>').html(result.pro_id));
$('.table tr:last').before($tr);
                           //$('#table').html('<tr><td>'+result+'</td></tr>');
                        }
                    });

            return false;
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Please post what you're getting inside the success method after calling `console.log(result);` !!

Comment: i'm getting nothing ..coz i couldnot figure out how to echo value for console.log(result); @PalashMondal

Comment: You're positive something like `echo 'test';` doesn't show up in `result.data` when you inspect it in your client-side debugger?

Comment: i need that test like u commented to echo..so i can display.

Comment: Can you show us your "view" file (codeigniter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think you don't need to return the result back from your model WHY? because you sending the data which is enter in the form, so when you are sending data through ajax, don't don't send the whole form by serializing it. Get value of each text field send it as string and if the result is true show that variables in rows
but if you still want to show it from data than, after inserting the record through model, than

```
public function payment_insert() {
    $this->load->model('payment_model');
    $amount = $this->input->post('amount');
    $paid_date = $this->input->post('paid_date');
    $project = $this->input->post('e1');


    $data = array(
       'paid_date' => $paid_date,
       'amount' => $amount,
       'pro_id' => $project
     );

    $feed= $this->payment_model->pinsert($data);
    print json_encode($feed);
  }

public function pinsert($data) {       
   $this->db->insert('payment', $data);
   $last_id = $this->db->last_id();//return last inserted id
   $this->db->where('id',$last_id);
   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->result_row();
}
```

you can also just return the last inserted id and than fetch the record from another function of model by passing this id to it. 
I hope it will help you

Comment: thank u this helped me slightly but how can i display on last row..my following code is not working for it

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo site_url("payment/payment_insert"); ?>",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: post_data,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(result)
                    {
                     //console.log(result);
                      $.each(result,function(key,value){
                         var NewRow = '<tr><td">'+value.p_id+'</td>';
                             NewRow += '<td>'+value.project_title+'</td>';
                             NewRow += '<td>'+value.amount+'</td>';
                             NewRow += '<td>'+value.paid_date+'</td>';
                             NewRow += '<td>'+value.pro_id+'</td>';
                             NewRow += '</tr>';

                             $(".table").append(NewRow);
                      });
                    }
                });

        return false;
        });
```

I hope this will solve your problem. when you append a new thing it automatically goes to the end

Answer (score 1):

Check this link

[Using jQuery and ajax with Codeigniter](http://www.jotorres.com/2012/01/using-jquery-and-ajax-with-codeigniter/)

and remember one thing, without echoing you cant get ajax data.

Answer (score 0):

you need to `json_encode($result)` your result in your controller.

and in jquery ajax request need to returning result in json format like this

```
dataType : 'json'
```

I think it will help.

Comment: you can use as you did before in success function